# Convert number of scientific format with with negative exponent to MaTeX?

Tags: matex, exponent

**MaTeX** can convert many data to **LaTeX** format, such as:

```mathematica
MaTeX[1.26591*^100]
```

will output

[image]

But when the number has a minus of the exponent, **MaTeX** wouldn't work right. Such as:

```mathematica
MaTeX[1.26591*^-100]
```

will output

[image]

As there are so many numbers with negative exponent, it is not good way to modify them one by one, so how should we do it automatically?

Comment: I think the problem is with `TeXForm` itself and not MaTeX. Compare `TeXForm[1.26591*10*^100]` output with `TeXForm[1.26591*^-100]` output and you will see why. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfWY0.png)

Comment: @Nasser Yes! I agreed with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround

```
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{siunitx}"}];
num = 1.26591*^-100;
MaTeX["\\num{" <> ToString@FortranForm[num] <> "}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not want the group separator space, do

```
MaTeX["\\num[group-separator =]{" <> ToString@FortranForm[num] <> "}",
  Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
num = 1.26591*^100
MaTeX["\\num{" <> ToString@FortranForm[num] <> "}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option if you want is to use the FortranForm directly and now you do not have to use the siunitx package.

```
 MaTeX[FortranForm[1.26591*^-100], Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest another method than @Nasser.
In practice, there can be several pieces bad-formatted by `TeXForm`, and we can preprocess the TeX expression by string patterns.

```
texForm[string_String] :=
    StringReplace[$texRule][string];
texForm[expr_] :=
    StringReplace[$texRule]@ToString@TeXForm[expr];
```

where `$texRule` stores the rules like

```
$texRule = {
    RegularExpression["(\\\\text{)([0-9.]+?)(\\\\$\\\\grave{ }\\\\$\\*\\\\${}\\^{\\\\wedge}\\\\$-)(\\d+?)(})"]->"$2 \\times 10^{-$4} "
};
```

then using `MaTeX` we get for example

```
a+1.26591*^-100 f[x]//texForm//MaTeX
```

\begin{equation}
a+1.26591 \times 10^{-100}  f(x)
\end{equation}